# updated state problem reactjs is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

in the following code i have a blank input . i need to see the updated states of input  in the console but whenever i type anything in the input i get error setSavedinput  is not defined .any help

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const blankinput = () => {
  const [Savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState("");
};
const Changesaved = (e) => {
  setSavedinput(e.target.value);
  console.log(Savedinput);
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={Changesaved}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The are some problems in your code. In order to make it works you need to do the following changes:

```
export default function App() {
  const [Savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState("");

  const Changesaved = (e) => {
    setSavedinput(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={Changesaved}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you need to `console.log` whenever `Savedinput` changes, then you need to add a `useEffect` with that state as dependency, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(Savedinput)
}, [Savedinput])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks (like `useState`) and the associated functions that modify them (like your `Changesaved`) need to go *inside* the function component, not outside.  The following should work:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [Savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState("");
  const Changesaved = (e) => {
    setSavedinput(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value); // Savedinput doesn't change immediately
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={Changesaved}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `react-hooks` in your component, not outside of the component body.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
      const [Savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState("");
      const Changesaved = (e) => {
        setSavedinput(e.target.value);
        console.log(Savedinput);
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input type="Text" onChange={Changesaved}></input>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Here's the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-water-bd04k